# Is it possible to add a Google Drive UI or frame into an existing website?

Tags: google-drive-api

Is it possible to add a Google Drive UI to an existing website?  We offer a CRM to many clients and want to be able to have them log into their Google Drive accont and drop/pull fiels from it while on the website we provide.

If this exact question has already been answered, then please direct me to the response.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Drive Picker to access and upload files from/to Google Drive.

https://developers.google.com/picker/